# AppEngine Connected Android Project not working after update

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-c2dm

I updated my SDK tools and SDK platform tools to the latest and to my horror found that AppEngine Connected Android project's emulator not launching if  I do **Debug as > Local AppEngine connected Android Project**.

I am working on a project and also have done quite a lot of work using this plugin option. Is there a way that I can still develop. Maybe someway I could start the AppEngine Seperately and Android Project Separately and still they would work( debugging as remote AppEngine is not a problem).

To what I have read, I think they doing it because they are deprecating C2DM messaging. And instead they bringing the option of Make AppEngine Backends. But unfortunately they have still not worked on the docs or support.

Is there any way I can still keep working till they release the docs or how can I make the transition myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I debug localy since the sdk update:

- Debug the app engine project as Web Application
- Run the AVD with the manager
- Debug the android project as Android Application

Remotely:

- Run the AVD with the manager
- Run the android project as Android Application

Hope this helps.

Edit:

After debugging remotely it seems that the AVD still speaks to the remote server eventhough you wipe out data and ask for "Debug android project". In this case do a "Debbug as local app engine connected android application". This will start the local server but not the Android app. Then Debug the android project as Android Application and it will talk to the local server.